# Post array to php from c#

Tags: c#, php, arrays, webrequest

I am currently working on a c#/php project where I need to retrieve some data from the database in c# and the data to an array and send the array to php.

While I am looping through the database I am adding string values into a string list array and once it has finished I then call:

```
string[] myData = myList.toArray();
```

I am then trying to post myData to php by using the following code

```
Dictionary<string, string> report = new Dictionary<string, string>();
report.add("data", myData.toString());
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(domain + appRoot + "/administrator/engine/email-alarms.php");
                    request.Method = "POST";
                    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> data in report)
                    {
                        b.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(data.Key)).Append("=").Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(data.Value ?? "")).Append("&");
                    }
                    string postData = b.ToString(0, b.Length - 1);
                    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

                    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                    dataStream.Close();

                    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Console.writeLine(response);
```

I realise saying myData.toString() isn't the correct thing to do as it just prints System.String[] but if I don't do this then I get an error in the c# code saying that there is an invalid argument.

How can I do post the array to php?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to serialize `string[]` (not clear but I think you wanted that, was the real question here), then just ...

```
string.Join(",", myData)
```

should output e.g. `1, 2, 3...`

Answer (score 3):

you can always use the `json` format as your exchange contract format and convert it back to their native representation and deal with your data accordingly. Both c# and php have functions/libraries that support the json format.

C# you serialize using:

```
var postData=new JavascriptSerializer().Serialize(object);
```

and in PHP you can use the `json_decode()` method. I'm not sure how it works in php.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: Changed to not even need a `List<string>`. You can iterate your original array. Added PHP code.

If you are expecting `$_POST["data"]` in your PHP script to be a string array, there is **no need** to serialize to JSON or some other format. PHP can accept arrays posted just fine. You just have to go about it the right way.

Change this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> report = new Dictionary<string, string>();
report.add("data", myData.toString());
// ...
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> data in report)
{
    b.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(data.Key)).Append("=").Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(data.Value ?? "")).Append("&");
}
```

to this (you no longer need the `List<string>` since you can iterate through your array directly and create a postable array:

```
foreach (string data in myData)
{
    b.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode("data[]")).Append("=").Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(data ?? "")).Append("&");
}
```

This will result in the `data` key in your POST from this:

```
string[] myData = new [] { "blah", "something", "else" };
```

being posted as this:

```
data[]=blah&data[]=something&data[]=else
```

This will result in the array being created successfully on the PHP side (I hope).

In PHP, you should then be able to do this:

```
foreach ($_POST["data"] as $value)
{
    echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably your best bet would be to encode it to JSON using [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) and then you can decode it in PHP with [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)